# How to reduce chrome initialization time?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've automated tests using Selenium WebDriver. When I run them for Chrome, some time chrome takes few minutes(upto 5 mins) to complete its launching. Following is code snippet for it -

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("chromeDriverPath"));
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1 );
    chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", DownloadFolderPathDriver);
    options.setExperimentalOption("w3c", false);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

    proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyIp+":"+proxyPort);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    options.merge(capabilities);
    driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Could you please suggest what could be reasons for its slowness and how to handle it?

Comment: Chrome is a memory and cpu hog, but launching it with Selenium shouldn't take longer than launching it manually. Are there any heavy process running on the machine? or is it low on memory in the first place? the only thing in your code that might ave an effect is the proxy. Did you try without it?

Comment: I can say not heavy processes running. As that machine has 16 GB RAM and 8 GB allocated for server and apart from that only Selenium tests run on it. If this is memory stuff, please guide on how I can allocate memory for Chrome for better performance.

Comment: You can find out easily if the issue is memory or cpu related, check the task manager before, during and after the script execution. AFAIK there is no way to manage chrome differently.

Comment: Can you comment out all initialization code except the bare minimum to open Chrome? Maybe one of the custom settings is the issue? Maybe the HTTP proxy? Other things to look into would be virus scanners. If virus scans are running they tend to hammer the hard drive, and the machine could be I/O bound causing the loading of data from the hard disk to run slow. This can definitely impact the start-up time for any application, including Chrome.

Comment: Which version of ChromeDriver and Chrome are you using?

Comment: Can you share any logs?